# Detail of class in output using list in c#

Tags: c#

Here is my person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string LastName;
    public int Age;

    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(string name, string lastName, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        LastName = lastName;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Here is my main program. The current output is `ListDemo.Person`. ListDemo is my solution name and `Person` is my class name. How can I get the all details of a person in an output?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Ahmad", LastName = "Ashfaq", Age = 20 });
        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Ali", LastName = "Murtza", Age = 23 });

        foreach (Person item in personList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Override the `.ToString()` method in the person class, and return a string with the data you want to be printed in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string LastName;
    public int Age;

    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(string name, string lastName, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        LastName = lastName;
        Age = age;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} - {2} Years Old", Name, LastName, Age);
    }
}
```

Which you can use exactly how you were in the original place:

```
foreach (Person item in personList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Which will print out like:

```
Jane Doe - 23 Years Old
John Doe - 14 Years Old
Jim Doe - 120 Years Old
```

The `.ToString()` is inherited from `Object` and is available to override on every class you create. You can use it to return string data that represents the object. By default this just returns the type name `ListDemo.Person` as you found out, but if you override it, you can return whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Edite your code to be like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Ahmad", LastName = "Ashfaq", Age = 20 });
        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Ali", LastName = "Murtza", Age = 23 });

        foreach (Person item in personList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
Console.WriteLine(item.LastName);
Console.WriteLine(item.Age);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Last Name = {1}, Age = {2}", item.Name, item.LastName, item.Age);
```

That will output the data you are looking for by going through the properties in the `item`s and giving you the output you desire.

Likewise, if you are looking for *default* behavior of generating a string from your class, you can override the `ToString()` method for your class to give the output you desire.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name = {0}, Last Name = {1}, Age = {2}", Name, LastName, Age);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override te `ToString` method in your `Person` class. The result of that function is what's printed. Insert the following code into your `Person` class:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return string.Format("Name: {0}, LastName: {1}, Age: {2}", Name, LastName, Age);
}
```

Alternatively, if you do not want the string representation of your class to change. You could print the string generated with the above code instead of printing the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

Beside of using `ToString()` method that is useful to output single value i am surprised that no one mentioned that you can create custom extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` (interface that is implemented by `List<T>`) to print all your values :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void Print(this IEnumerable<Person> people)
    {
        foreach(Person p in people) 
           Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name : {0}, Last Name : {1}, Age : {2}", p.Name, p.LastName, p.Age));
    }
}
```

And use it in a way like if it was defined in `List<T>`  :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Ahmad", LastName = "Ashfaq", Age = 20 });
        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Ali", LastName = "Murtza", Age = 23 });

        personList.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that this code is not determining how a `Person` would be printed. Instead it is telling how to print a very specific (List<Person>) data type. If someone will try to print a single `Person`, he'll get the same output that OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @displayName And this is exactly why i wrote "*with all being said*"... OP can use both this method to print `List<Person>` and `ToString()` to output single Person instance...